# Django: form validation errors are not being displayed when form is in a modal

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a Django web app that will be able to add and display certain information in a database (the Agent model seen below) I have a form in a twitter bootstrap modal. When I enter valid data and submit, everything works as expected and the modal redirects to the view page. However, when I enter invalid information, instead of redisplaying the modal with the validation errors displayed, it redirects to an empty page. I have the view printing out the validation errors and everything is there, it just isn't showing on the page. When I remove the modal class from the template (so it displays on the page instead of in a modal), the error information is displayed. How do I get it to display in the modal?

View:

```
class AgentAddView(CreateView):
    model = Agent
    template_name = "agent_form.html"
    success_url = '/ui/all_agents'
    form_class = NewAgentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        print('hererererer')
        return redirect('/ui/all_agents')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

Form:

```
class NewAgentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        fields = ['hostname', 'ip_address', 'domain', 'username', 'password', 'password', 'encrypted']

    hostname = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Hostname'}))
    ip_address = forms.GenericIPAddressField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'placeholder': 'IP Address'}), label="IP Address")
    domain = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Domain'}))
    username = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}), required=False)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}), required=False)
    is_encrypted = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base_page.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="modal fade" id="add-agent-modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>Add Agent</h3>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'add_agent' %}">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Add</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You would have to submit the form via ajax, or the POST request for the form will reload the view, causing the modal to disappear. It's visibility is triggered via a client-side event, so to keep it visible, your form submission has to be via ajax.

Comment: Doing everything via AJAX might be better in the long run, but see my answer below for a quick and dirty way to make the modal show if the user's input failed to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write some javascript to sense whether the form has been submitted and found invalid, and if so display the modal.

You can set a javascript global variable in your template based on the error state:

```
<script>
    document.formHasErrors = {% if form.errors %}true{% else %}false{% endif %};
</script>
```

Then you can [use javascript to tell the modal to open](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript).

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       if (document.formHasErrors) {
           $('#add-agent-modal').modal('toggle');
       }
    });
</script>
```

It's not particularly beautiful, but it should be effective.

Comment: That worked, thanks! It still reloads the page which isn't ideal, but that is unavoidable without AJAX.